# Creating custom login forms

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to create custom form with some custom submit code. I am using devise to sign people in. I'm creating the opportunity for people to create a session with a nickname without creating a permanent user account. I'm trying to work out, where do I need to put my code for the:
*ERB
*Rails

I don't believe I need to create more controllers using generate, but I'm not sure where to put the stuff without this to help.

Answer (score 0):

You can use devise specific generators to pull out the view and controller you need, then you can alter those to fit your needs. Another option is to generate a small scaffold and use routes.rb to override parts of the devise API.  I prefer the first option--it will reduce the amount of conceptual clutter and I believe this is how devise is intended to be used.